# How do you disable a checkbox on the page_load event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

how to auto disable asp.net checkbox1 on page_load event ?

only vb.net code required !!

Comment: Try not to shout at people you are asking help from.

Comment: @Jack - not understanding the "shout" comment.

Comment: "only vb.net required !!"  - could simply just ask "VB.net code only please

Comment: hmm, not sure if I classify that as shouting.

Comment: maybe not shouting, but it's acting like an ass

Answer (score 3):

Disabling a checkbox is easy

```
checkbox1.Enabled = False
```

In the Page_Load event, it would look something like this.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ''# checkbox1 should not be enabled on page load.
    checkbox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected sub page_load
 checkboxname.Enabled = false
end sub
```